# How can I use a locally installed NodeJS library in Python?

Tags: python, typescript

I want to use this NodeJS library for a Python based data science project:

https://github.com/gigobyte/HLTV

I think I've installed the API correctly but I don't know how I can use it in a Python script.

Comment: `npm install -g ts-node`, then from Python you can use `subprocess.call(['ts-node', 'script.ts'])`... This still requires you to **write** TypeScript code

Comment: Or... Just [use Python](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=HLTV&type=Repositories)